# How insert hyperlink from a column into Outlook email body

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have column "AB" that has a hyperlink in which I will like to include in a email through VBA.

The hyperlink changes per line. I am able to pull the column through text however the email is not showing the hyper link.

How can I get it to show as a hyperlink?

```
Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strto As String, strcc As String, strbcc As String
    Dim strsub As String, strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strto = Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "Y").Value
    strcc = ""
    strbcc = ""
    strsub = "MCR FORM"
    strbody = "Hi " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "O").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "You have a open MCR that needs attention. Please Find the attachted MCR Form for material : " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "E").Value & _
              vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "AB").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Thank you!"


    With OutMail
        .To = strto
        .CC = strcc
        .BCC = strbcc
        .Subject = strsub
        .Body = strbody
        'You can add a file to the mail like this
        .Attachments.Add ("P:\Inventory Control\Public\MCR Form Master.xlsm")
        .Display    ' or use .Send
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

```
vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "AB").Value &
```

I believe the code above needs to be reference a HREF link??

Comment: Hello, thank your for the response. This example wouldn't work for me. The example below is in reference to cell A1 (with A1 being the hyperlink). In my worksheet I have a entire column with different hyper links. I will need  the email to grab the row of the hyperlink. If I'm not mistaken... I will have to have this line: 'Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "AB").Value'    ...... as the hyperlink.  Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: `FormulaCell` will throw error, can you post an example of your spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

*Work with [HTMLBody Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa171418(v=office.11))*

---

*Example will show Hyperlink [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55715839/vba-insert-hyperlink-from-a-column-into-outlook-email)*

> ```
> .HTMLBody = "<A href=" & Sht.Range("A1") & "> Click Here </A>"
> ```

*Or This will show the value A1 as link*

> ```
> "<A href=" & Sht.Range("A1") & ">" & Sht.Range("A1") & "</A>" &
> ```

---

*Full Code*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    
    Dim Sht As Excel.Worksheet
    Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ""
        
        .HTMLBody = "Hi " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "You have a open MCR that needs attention. " & _
                     vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                     "<A href=" & Sht.Range("A1") & "> Click Here </A>" & _
                     vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Thank you!"
                    
        'You can add a file to the mail like this
        .Display    ' or use .Send
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

*[Option Explicit Statement (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement)*

*Forces explicit declaration of all variables in a file, or allows implicit declarations of variables.*